# When I store several dataframes in a list of dataframes and I recall one of them, is there a way to format the column header of the output?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am new to Python and Stackoverflow, so please bear with me. I have a large datafile of roughly 140k rows stored as a csv. The file is split up into sections based on age groups, ie. 16-24, 24-50 etc. At every break there are information lines about the age and etnicity of the subjects. After loading the csv into pandas, I tried to break up the dataframe into several smaller ones by dividing on the information lines of the age groups using iloc. Now I have a list of dataframes. I can access each dataframe in the list, no problem, however (I guess due to the information lines) pandas displays all information in one column. Is there a way to format the output and make pandas display the column headers and put the information lines into the header above the column headers? I'm sorry if this is not very clear, please feel free to suggest any edits.

The data in the csv looks something like this:

```
0 Some information
1 Some information
2 Some information
3 
4 
5 a | b | c | d |
6 a | 1 | 1 | 1 |
7 a | 1 | 1 | 1 |
8 a | 1 | 1 | 1 |
9
10 Some information
11 Some information
12 Some information
13 
14 
15 a | b | c | d |
16 a | 1 | 1 | 1 |
17 a | 1 | 1 | 1 |
18 a | 1 | 1 | 1 |
```

I used iloc to break this up on the information lines by row index.

```
         36065,43278,50491,57704,
         64917,72130,79343,86556,
         93769,100982,108195,115408,
         122621,129834,137047]
    l_mod = [0] + l + [max(l)+1]

    list_of_dfs = [mydata_df.iloc[l_mod[n]:l_mod[n+1]] for n in range(len(l_mod)-1)]
```

when accessing I used: `df1_df=list_of_dfs[1]`

The output is currently as follows:

```
                  0
--------------------
1 a,b,c
2 a,1,1,
```

I hope this makes sense, please suggest edits and I'll do my best to explain.

Comment: Are the values delimited by a comma like your example output?

Comment: Yes, they are. Thank you for the edit btw!

Comment: Thank you so much for that! It worked. Much appreciated, very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)`, which expands your dataframe based on every split on a comma. Then you can assign the new column names to it, since it will give column names `[0, 1, 2, 3.. etc]`